# phpUnit with Symfony

Tags: phpunit, symfony

I have successfully setup a symfony 3.2.4 project with the following commands :

```
symfony new symfony_test
cd symfony_test
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^6.0
composer update
```

Then I have the following error when I try to run the default test :

```
$ vendor/bin/phpunit tests/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php

Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in C:\Users\po.louis\PhpstormProjects\test\symfony_test\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase.php on line 23
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: You are testing the Symfony code from your project as well - and you will be pulling in a lot of other libraries as well, most of them (you'd hope) with many more tests. It will be useful to limit the tests you run to your own project/code (with phpunit.xml's 'whitelists'), and trust that the libraries (like Symfony) are well tested on their own - or go to the libraries and do a local `composer install` within them, to make sure you have all the support required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not possibile yet on same version of the framework, [as announced in the last weekly update](http://symfony.com/blog/a-week-of-symfony-530-20-26-february-2017):

> This week Symfony continued [refactoring tests](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/c55b7349ae4bcc5508de0d89047ea80f07307631) to make use of the
>   new PHPUnit namespaces.

Hope this will be available on all the supported version.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your composer.json edit

`phpunit/phpunit ^6.0`

to

`phpunit/phpunit ^5.7`

and all works fine.

As Matteo wrote to you isn't supported yet 6.0 version